# Как запретить Firebase кэшировать фотографии на телефон

Tags: java, android, kotlin

В приложение есть возможность добавлять фотографии, они отображаются в recyclerview  и по не понятной причине Firebase их сохраняет на устройство. Для чего он это делает, как отключить это? Вес приложения после загрузки 10 фото доходит до 100 мегабайт.

Класс для загрузки записей в базу данных

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_post);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    UnderlineSettings();

    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null && data != null){

        mImageUri = data.getData();

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mImageUri).into(mini);
        mini.setImageURI(mImageUri);
    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.image_select)
public void OpenGallery(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
@OnClick(R.id.info_help)
public void Help(){
    new CustomBottomHelperGroup().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Dialog");
}
@OnClick(R.id.close_post)
public void ClosePostCreater(){
    finish();
}
@OnClick(R.id.add_post)
public void AddPost(){
    Upload();
    finish();
}

private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
}

private void Upload(){
    if (mImageUri != null) {

        fileReference = storage.child(getFileExtension(mImageUri) + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis());

        mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot ->

                fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    upload = new Upload(text.getText().toString(), task.getResult().toString(), choose, "0");

                    uploadId = data.push().getKey();
                    data.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                })).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Не выбрано фото!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

Адаптер recyclerview


class RecyclerAdapter(val context: Context, private val data: List<Upload>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val uploadCurrent = data[position]
    holder.mainText.text = uploadCurrent.name
    holder.like.text = uploadCurrent.getmLike()
    Glide.with(context).load(uploadCurrent.imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.place).centerCrop().into(holder.imageFeed)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_content, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view, context, data)
}

override fun getItemCount() = data.size


class ViewHolder(view: View, context: Context, data: List<Upload>) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    init {
        view.setOnClickListener{}

        view.delete.setOnClickListener{
            val mDataBaseReg: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads")
            val mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
            val upload: Upload = data[position]
            val selectedKey = upload.code
            val imageRef: StorageReference = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(upload.imageUrl)
            imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener {
                mDataBaseReg.child(selectedKey).removeValue()
                Toast.makeText(context, "Запись удалена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        view.like.setOnClickListener {

            Toast.makeText(context, "like", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        view.ImageFeed.setOnClickListener{

            val intent = Intent(context, ImageViewer::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("image", data[position].imageUrl)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

        val mainText: AppCompatTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.MainText)
        val imageFeed: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.ImageFeed)
        val like: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.like_count)
    }
}

Класс для показа записей

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mDatabaseRef.removeEventListener(mDBListener);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_administrator_feed);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    toolbar.setTitle(" ");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    showDialog();
    UnderlineSettings();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MODE, MODE_PRIVATE);
    mode1 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(MODE, mode1);

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(AdministratorFeed.this, list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    mDatabaseRef.keepSynced(false);

    if(mode1){
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }else{
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }
    mDBListener = mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = snapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                upload.setCode(snapshot.getKey());
                list.add(upload);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            all.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            first.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            second.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            third.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            fourth.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public void UnderlineSettings(){

    all.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = snapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    upload.setCode(snapshot.getKey());
                    list.add(upload);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        all.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        first.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        second.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        third.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        fourth.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    });

    first.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Query query_first = mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("mChoise").equalTo("1");
        query_first.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = snapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    upload.setCode(snapshot.getKey());
                    list.add(upload);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        all.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        first.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        second.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        third.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        fourth.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    });

    second.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Query query_second = mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("mChoise").equalTo("2");
        query_second.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = snapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    upload.setCode(snapshot.getKey());
                    list.add(upload);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        all.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        first.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        second.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        third.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        fourth.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    });

    third.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Query query_third = mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("mChoise").equalTo("3");
        query_third.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = snapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    upload.setCode(snapshot.getKey());
                    list.add(upload);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        all.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        first.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        second.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        third.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        fourth.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    });

    fourth.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Query query_fourth = mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("mChoise").equalTo("4");
        query_fourth.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = snapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    upload.setCode(snapshot.getKey());
                    list.add(upload);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        all.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        first.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        second.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        third.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        fourth.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    });
}
```

Comment: У Glide включено кэширование?

Comment: Я использую вызов Glide в recycleradapter вот так- Glide.with(context).load(uploadCurrent.imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.place).centerCrop().into(holder.imageFeed) и в меню отправки изображения(отображается в миниатюре) в базу данных - Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mImageUri).into(mini); Кэширование вроде никакого нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сделать

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);
```

потому что firebase по дефолту кэширует данные, чтобы их можно было юзать оффлайн.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог этот метод в glide чтобы не кэшировать данные -

Glide.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
  .into(imageView);